# Supposedly six OFAC sanctioned transactions were missing from blocks. Which transactions are these?

Tags: transactions, censorship-resistance

As of today Nov 21, 2023. A user on twitter reported about the missing transactions from blocks. Which transactions is this user talking about? And how is it missing from blocks? Why can't it just get mined by another pool?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the full article? I'm pretty sure it answers all your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers to these questions are in [the article](https://b10c.me/observations/08-missing-sanctioned-transactions) linked in the tweet you're screenshotting:

> Which transactions is this user talking about?

Their txids are:

- 262025e73812fc68b6514ea366abf463147176c7867e5853f117aded58c30e0e
- c9b5719131bfeac6378749243731c5e70f1ce56deabb7006a2b6539710866420
- c6a668364f19df0f2977f8ad7d0a3a73c5e32b55b6a7c650cafa37a5ab4b19f2
- aa001ce6e262b8b9042645ecdec9c84e9e2ad06f56dff6dd5ae42005fdea8da9
- 1cb3d6bcc650c2891b68e7b205d601bcf5158e30e1926d0fd0c8385cb456b37b
- e49cdb6075c49b8fc37b3e922038e2a3205d75a9a1fb4b69f3568707594c2d3e

> And how is it missing from blocks?

These transactions were relayed on the network, looked like they had sufficient fee to be included, but somehow were not included in the blocks that followed.

> Why can't it just get mined by another pool?

They *were*. These transactions aren't censored from the network. They're just surprisingly missing from specific blocks that could have included them. The article explains how it concludes that in *some* of these cases, it appears likely that this was due to OFAC filtering. The fact that certain pools appear to be doing such filtering is on itself interesting (if the conclusions of the article's author are correct), even if that's entirely ineffective due to the fact that the same transactions will just be mined by others.